# Atmega88P ADC not working

Tags: led, adc, atmega, potentiometer

I have an Atmega88P (default 1 MHz clock) and I'm trying to have a LED blink and to regulate the luminosity of another one using the potentiometer. For the first LED I used TIMER/COUNTER0 in CTC mode and it works. For the second one, I used the TIMER/COUNTER2 to create a PWM wave with the fast PWM mode, wich also works just fine. The problem comes when I try to change de duty cycle of the PWM wave with the value obtained from the ADC conversion of the potentiometer.
I've used a multimeter to check if the potenciometer works and it does, but every time I upload the code the LED just stays at a constant luminosity.

```c
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


#define BLINK_LED_PIN PD4
#define INSTENSITY_LED_PIN PD3

#define LED_TOGGLE_TIME 500 //ms
#define TIMER0_CYCLE_TIME 10 //ms
#define MAX_LED_BLINK_CNT (LED_TOGGLE_TIME / TIMER0_CYCLE_TIME)

volatile uint16_t led_blink_cnt = 0;
uint8_t adc_value = 0;



// Called every 10 ms
ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
    
    // Blink LED every 50 cycles (1 Hz)
    if (++led_blink_cnt >= MAX_LED_BLINK_CNT) {
        
        PORTD ^= (1 << BLINK_LED_PIN);
        led_blink_cnt = 0;
        
    }
}


// Check if the ADC is occupied converting
bool is_adc_converting() {
    return (bool) (ADCSRA & (1 << ADSC));
}


// Setup for the Timer/Counter 0 (1 ms)
void setup_timer0() {
    // CTC Mode
    TCCR0A &= ~(1 << WGM00);
    TCCR0A |= (1 << WGM01);
    TCCR0B &= ~(1 << WGM02);

    // Normal port operation
    TCCR0A &= ~((1 << COM0A0) | (1 << COM0A1));

    // Prescaler (64)
    TCCR0B |= (1 << CS00) | (1 << CS01);
    TCCR0B &= ~(1 << CS02);

    // Compare value
    OCR0A = 155;

    // Enable interrupts
    TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A);
}


// Setup for the Timer/Counter 2 (PWM)
void setup_timer2() {
    // Fast PWM Mode
    TCCR2A |= (1 << WGM20) | (1 << WGM21);
    TCCR2B &= ~(1 << WGM22);

    // Clear OC2B on Compare Match, set OC2B at BOTTOM, (non-inverting mode).
    TCCR2A &= ~(1 << COM2B0);
    TCCR2A |= (1 << COM2B1);

    // Prescaler (No prescaling)
    TCCR2B |= (1 << CS20);
    TCCR2B &= ~((1 << CS21) | (1 << CS22));

    //Compare value
    OCR2B = 0;  // Arbitrary initial value
}


// Setup for the ADC
void setup_adc() {
    // Set ADC as ADC0
    ADMUX &= ~((1 << MUX0) | (1 << MUX1) | (1 << MUX2) | (1 << MUX3));

    // AREF
    ADMUX &= ~((1 << REFS1) | (1 << REFS0));
    
    // Left adjust the result
    ADMUX |= (1 << ADLAR);
    
    // Enable ADC
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN);
    
    // Set the division factor to 16
    ADCSRA &= ~((1 << ADPS1) | (1 << ADPS0));
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADPS2);

}

void setup_ports() {
    // Set PD4 and PD3 as outputs
    DDRD |= (1 << BLINK_LED_PIN);
    DDRD |= (1 << INSTENSITY_LED_PIN);
    
    // Turn off the led
    PORTD &= ~(1 << BLINK_LED_PIN);
    
    // Set PC0 as input
    DDRC &= ~(1 << PC0);
    
}


// Runs once when the program starts
void setup() {
    cli();
    
    setup_timer0();
    setup_timer2();
    setup_adc();
    setup_ports();

    sei();  // Start timers/counters
}


// Runs every frame
void loop() {
    ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);
    while(ADCSRA & (1<<ADSC));
    
    adc_value = ADCH;

    OCR2B = adc_value;

}


int main() {
    
    setup();
    while (true)
        loop();

    return 0;
}
```

I think the problem is in the ADC setup. I've tried plenty of other setups such as free running mode, with an ISR, ...

Comment: Put the schematic of the circuit setup.

Comment: "The problem comes when I try to change de duty cycle of the PWM wave with the value obtained from the ADC conversion of the potentiometer." --- So before this, how you managed to vary the duty cycle of PWM and found success?

Comment: What value does the ADC read at min and max input voltages?  What are the values of the voltages measured on the ADC input pin?